# Problemas al abrir Jupyter Notebook - Python

Tags: python, jupyter

Acabo de reinstalar python y el paquete para jupyter notebook, sin embargo al correr desde el cmd jupyter notebook me aparece el siguiente mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

verifico la instalación y me dice que tiene todos los paquetes requeridos instalados
Saben por que puede ocurrir esto? o si se debe correr el cmd de manera diferente?
Esto debido a que cuando reinstalé python debo instalar los paquetes como py -m pip install, mientras que antes solo bastaba con decir pip install, no se si tenga algo que ver o si debo cambiar el directorio

Muchas gracias, saludos

Comment: El problema está en la configuración del Path de Windows. No obstante, si tienes varias versiones de Python usar el Python Launcher es una buena opción (independientemente de usar entornos virtuales) permitiendote especificar el intérprete a usar en cada momento. `py -m jupyter nootbook` (versión por defecto de Python) o `py -3.6 -m jupyter notebook` (para usar Python 3.6),  `py -2.7 -m jupyter notebook` (para usar Python 2.7), etc  debe funcionar sin problemas. Presupongo que has instalado Jupyter desde pip y no usando Anaconda.

Comment: En mi caso tuve que usar: "python -m jupyter nootbook" y me corrió. Pero no entiendo porque no puedo usar simplemente  "jupyter nootbook". Acabo de verificar que esté instalado en la misma carpeta de la versión de Python usada y está instalado. Asi que una gran incógnita.

Answer (score 1):

Hola gracias por la respuesta, en este momento solo tengo instalada la versión 3.6
He intentado todas las opciones que mencionas pero en todos los casos encuentro el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También intenté cambiar el path de windows y nada

A la final me ha funcionado cambiando el cd a la carpeta de scripts de python:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts"
```

En caso de que alguien más lo necesite

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Instalé JupyterLab 1.0: Jupyter’s Next-Generation Notebook Interface por medio de pip en powershell y tenía el mismo problema, no fue necesario modificar el Path global, el path para mi usuario tenía la dirección donde python estaba intalado. Revisé la carpeta de Scripts y ahí estaba jupyter-lab.exe. En el Power shell en lugar de poner

```
python -m jupyter notebook
```

sólo escribí directamente

```
jupyter-lab.exe
```

e inició jupyter sin problemas

Answer (score 0):

Luego de reinstalar python y actualizar pip, instale jupyter, pero al igual que muchos, no me funciono. Mire si estaba instalado en pip y, efectivamente estaba instalado, pero no abria con ningun comando... Luego de inetar con todo, encontre el siguente comando " *python -m notebook* ", el cual hizo que me saliera el siguente mensaje:

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:

*file:///C:/Users/David%20Iba%C3%B1ez%20Miranda/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-10132-open.html*

Lo unico que hice fue copiar el link en el navegador y se abrio jupyter v: #FuiFeliz